# How to apply function on the basis of column condition in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a function over a column in a dataframe if one of the column i.e. df['mask']  contain False it should skip that row. mask column is bool type

this is mine function

```
     def dates(inp):
        temp = inp
        parser = CommonRegex()
        inp = inp.apply(parser.dates).str.join(', ')
        return np.where(inp.apply(parser.dates).str.len() == 0, temp, 'X' * random.randrange(3, 8))
```

here what i have applied

```
      df1.assign(**df1['Dates'].apply(dates).where(df1['mask']== TRUE))
```

Its throwing error

```
         32     temp = inp
         33     parser = CommonRegex()
    ---> 34     inp = inp.apply(parser.dates).str.join(', ')
         35     return np.where(inp.apply(parser.dates).str.len() == 0, temp, 'X' * random.randrange(3, 8))
         36 

    AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Here is mine dataframe look like

```
         Name     |  Dates   |  mask |
         ..............................
         Tom      | 21/02/2018| True
         Nick     | 28/07/2018| False
         Juli     | 11/08/2018| True
         June     | 01/02/2018| True
         XHGM     | 07/08/2018| False
```

I am trying to get output in this way that for false value it should skip and and for true value it should call date function and hide the data values

```
         Name     |  Dates   |  mask |
         ..............................
         Tom      | XXXXX     | True
         Nick     |28/07/2018 | False
         Juli     | XXXXX     | True
         June     | XXXXX     | True
         XHGM     | 07/08/2018| False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pipe.html) for pass columns to function and also filter rows with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by mask and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for specify column name:

```
df1.loc[df1['mask'], 'Dates'] = df1.loc[df1['mask'], 'Dates'].pipe(dates)
print (df1)
   Name       Dates   mask
0   Tom         XXX   True
1  Nick  28/07/2018  False
2  Juli         XXX   True
3  June         XXX   True
4  XHGM  07/08/2018  False
```

Solution with `assign` is possible too, but disadvantage is function loop by all values and then filtering, so if only few `True`s values in large `Dataframe` should be slowier:

```
df1 = df1.assign(Dates = np.where(df1['mask'], df1['Dates'].pipe(dates), df1['Dates']))
```

Comment: hey @jezrael  it throws error expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @ParthTiwari - can you test only with sample data from question if same error?